# Different VirtualHosts with the same port

Tags: apache, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I need to have two VirtualHosts with the same listen port for different projects and with different logs. Here's what I've got:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/projects/smk
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/smk-error.log
        RedirectMatch ^/$ /cms
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/projects/smk/cms
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/smk-cms-error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/projects/smk/deploy
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/smk-deploy-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add different ServerName directive in all virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dev.localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/projects/smk/cms
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/smk-cms-error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName my-project.localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/projects/smk/deploy
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/smk-deploy-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to add host-entries for `dev.localhost` and `my-project.localhost` in `/etc/hosts` to `127.0.0.1` or whatever ip you want it to point to.

Comment: Just to add, it's required to add `NameVirtualHost *:80` in `httpd.conf` file. This was commented by default (Apache/2.2.34 (Unix))

Answer (score 0):

ServerName my-project.localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/projects/smk/deploy
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/smk-deploy-error.log

//Try adding Error document

ErrorDocument 404 404.html

There is a need to create a feedback in your application.