# Apache VirtualHost : multiple sites on same IP

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Let assume that `blah.com`, `blah2.com` all point to the same server with IP=`5.31.111.7`.

I would like that:

- accessing `blah.com` serves `/var/www/site1`
- accessing `blah2.com` serves `/var/www/site1`
- accessing `5.31.111.7` serves `/var/www/site2`

I tried

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 5.31.111.7:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
</VirtualHost>
```

but now everything goes to `/var/www/site2`, which is not what I wanted.

**How to configure the `VirtualHost`, such that the served website depends on the URL ?**

*PS: why should I do this in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` instead of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` ? I don't understand this `sites-enabled` / `sites-available/default`  naming... Why are there so many different config files by default on Debian, for such a simple thing?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [apache: different virtualhosts in the same port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069892/apache-different-virtualhosts-in-the-same-port)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is called [*Name-Based Virtual Hosting*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/name-based.html), you'll need

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

to enable it on port 80, and for each VirtualHost, you need to give the name(s):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName blah2.com
ServerAlias www.blah2.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that there are [limitations on SSL/TLS](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/ssl/ssl_faq.html#vhosts2) when doing name-based virtual hosting, but it's a bit of a moot point since post-POODLE, people start to require TLS anyway, so ancient browsers are out of luck anyway.

As to the config files, it's very very useful to have two classes of config files: the ones with defaults that a package update will overwrite, and your local ones that it will not touch, or better even, a directory full of the former and a directory full of the latter. (Because additional packages might want to make configuration settings, they'll all install in the former place, and you should only ever change/override config in the second place.)

Comment: Thanks! It worked with your code, even without `NameVirtualHost *:80`. About config files, what are exactly sites-enabled / sites-available ? It is not very explicit...

Comment: @Basj: I would assume that the intention is that you put symlinks from `sites-enabled` into `sites-available` for those sites you want to use. That way, you can quickly switch something off by removing the symlink, and you can prepare things in `sites-available` and not have to worry immediately about typos. (Remember, your coworker could be restarting the server while you're editing the config file.)